# Row wise calculations(Python)

Tags: python, pandas

Trying to run the following code to create a new column 'Median Rank':

```
N=data2.Rank.count()
for i in data2.Rank:
    data2['Median_Rank']=i-0.3/(N+0.4)
```

But I'm getting a constant value of 0.99802. Even though my rank column is as follows:

```
data2.Rank.head()
Out[464]: 
4131     1.0
4173     3.0
4172     3.0
4132     3.0
5335    10.0
4171    10.0
4159    10.0
5079    10.0
4115    10.0
4179    10.0
4180    10.0
4147    10.0
4181    10.0
4175    10.0
4170    10.0
4116    24.0
4129    24.0
4156    24.0
4153    24.0
4160    24.0
5358    24.0
4152    24.0
```

Somebody please point out the errors in my code.

Comment: provide some sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code isn't vectorised. Use this:

```
N = data2.Rank.count()
data2['Median_Rank'] = data2['Rank'] - 0.3 / (N+0.4)
```

The reason your code does not work is because you are assigning the *entire* column in *each* loop. So only the last `i` iteration sticks, values in `data2['Median_Rank']` are guaranteed to be identical.

Answer (score 1):

This occurs because every time you make `data2['Median_Rank']=i-0.3/(N+0.4)` you are updating the entire column with the value calculated by the expression, the easiest way to do that actually don't need a loop:

```
N=data2.Rank.count()
data2['Median_Rank'] = data2.Rank-0.3/(N+0.4)
```

It is possible because pandas supports element-wise operations with series.

if you still want to use `for` loop, you will need to use `.at` and iterate by rows as follow:

```
for i, el in zip(df_filt.index,df_filt.rendimento_liquido.values):
    df_filt.at[i,'Median_Rank']=el-0.3/(N+0.4)
```

Comment: Right..Thanks a lot